# How do I open a tab from with jQuery UI Tabs from an link outside of the div?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

This may be a little difficult to explain, but I'll try my best.  I have a product page with two tabs, full description and video.  These are done using jQuery UI Tabs.

Above this section of the page I have a product image with thumbnails...but I want one of the thumbnails to be a link to see the video (which of course is contained in the video tab).

If I load the page as site.com/product#video it does load up the correct tab...but when the tab is not active, and I use a link outside of the #tab div, (ex: Video), it doesn't do anything.

How can I get a link to open the tab if it's not contained in the #tab div?

**CODE**

***This code is outside of the tabs, and needs to open the #video tab***

```
<a href="#video">Open Video Tab</a>
```

***Tabs Code***

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
<ul class="product-tabs ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active ui-state-hover"><a href="#description">Full Description</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#video">Video</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="product-collateral">
    <div class="box-collateral box-description">
        <div id="description" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
           Content
        </div>
        <div id="video" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide">
            <h2 class="video">Video Content</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have any code you can share with us?

Comment: Added example code to the question.

Comment: You are going to have to give us more info. Right now it looks you will need to solve this with some jquery. a quick fix might to make that href absolute = hfef="http://www.site.com/product#video" if it work's that way. Otherwise you are going to need jquery to look for a hashchange. Send some links to like screenshots or a jfiddle?

Comment: Dear Plz also see this if you could resolve it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090656/mvc-go-to-specific-tab-using-jquery/20090718?noredirect=1#comment29932633_20090718

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What worked for me was this:

**Html**

```
<a href="#description" class="open-tab">Open Description Tab</a>
<a href="#video" class="open-tab">Open Video Tab</a>   

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#description">Full description</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#video">Video content</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="product-collateral">
        <div class="box-collateral box-description">
            <div id="description">
                Content
            </div>
            <div id="video">
                <h2 class="video">Video Content</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tabs').tabs();

    $('.open-tab').click(function (event) {
        var tab = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', tab);
    });
});
```

So what this does is provide a link to both the description and video tabs, which are selected when the link is clicked.

From [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#method-select) we can see that when selecting a particular tab, we can use either a zero-based index or the href fragment which points to the tab we wish to display.

This is why the `href` attributes of the `a` elements match up with the Ids of the `div` elements - when one is clicked its href fragment is then used to set the selected tab.

---

**Update for jQuery UI 1.11**

As jQuery UI has evolved, so to has the API for setting the active tab. As of jQuery UI 1.11, the following code will select the active tab:

```
//Selects by the zero-based index
$('#tabs').tabs("option", "active", index);
```

Now because we now have to provide a zero-based index, the code I initially provided will no longer work.

What we need now is an index that can actually be used. One approach is:

```
$('.open-tab').click(function (event) {
    var index = $("selector-of-clicked-tab").index();
    $('#tabs').tabs("option", "active", index);
});
```

Another is to use HTML5 `data-` attributes:

```
<a href="#description" class="open-tab" data-tab-index="0">Open Description Tab</a>
<a href="#video" class="open-tab" data-tab-index="1">Open Video Tab</a>
```

So you can do this when handling the click of these links:

```
$('.open-tab').click(function (event) {
    $('#tabs').tabs("option", "active", $(this).data("tab-index"));
});
```

Comment: I was able to get this working with your script here (see the video thumbnail):

http://store.carbonfibergear.com/pirate-carbon-stealthclip-pro-all-carbon-fiber-money-clip

But for some reason I am trying to do the same thing with the reviews link (under the thumbnails), and it's not working.  Do you have any idea why not?

Comment: Try adding the class `open-tab` to the link you are clicking. My answer assumes that the links that are used to open the tabs will have that class. Also, this block of code: `jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.yotpo .result_status').click(function(){
        jQuery('#tabs').tabs('select', "reviews");
    });
});` you should be able to delete as a result. If you wanted to you could also try changing `reviews` to `#reviews` to see if that works, but I think adding that class is the more general approach.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I unfortunately don't have the ability to add a class (the code is being pulled in from a plugin), which is why I'm using the .yotpo .result_status.  I tried doing #reviews and had no luck.  In theory it seems like it should work, but for some reason it's not.  Any other ideas?

Comment: `#reviews` didn't work? That seems strange. I think at this point we need to be certain that the `jQuery('.yotpo .result_status').click` handler is actually executing. You could also try using the index-based approach, i.e., `jQuery('#tabs').tabs('select', 2);`

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work either way, but how can I check if the handler is executing?  The only other thing I can see as an issue is that the link is going to #yoReviews, which is a div INSIDE of the #reviews tab...though I can't control the link, or the #yoReviews content.  Do you think that could be causing the problem?

Also, one more thing I'm thinking that could cause a problem...the way that link loads in after the site is loaded?

Comment: So the link loads after the page is loaded? That should be the problem, because the click handler won't be attached to anything. Try this: `jQuery(document).on('click', '.yotpo .result_status', function() { jQuery('#tabs').tabs('select', "#reviews"); });`

Comment: Calling tabs.('select', ...) is no longer part of the tabs api, use gnarly or chuckfinley solution below.

Comment: select method is not working anymore, you have to use active option, jQuery( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1);

Answer (score 9):

use jQuery:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ active: tabNumber });
```

Remember, that the indexation starts from 0

Comment: Can you got a little more in-depth, I'm not really sure I understand how I would utilize that to make it worth with a link outside of the div?

Answer (score 3):

Using jquery, bind a click event to your link that opens the tab you want.

```
$('#tabopenlink').click(function() {
    $('#tabs').tabs({active: tabidx});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use mini plug-in.

```
    (function($) {
    $.fn.tabremote = function(options) {

          var settings = $.extend({
           panel: "#tabs",
           to: "data-to",
        }, options );

        $this=$(this);
        $panel=$(settings.panel);

    $this.click(function(){
                if($(this).attr("href"))
                    {var tos=$(this).attr("href");}
                else
                    {var tos=$(this).attr(settings.to);}

                to=tos.match(/\d/g);
    $panel.tabs({active: to-1});        
    return false;   
    });


        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Opens the tab using href or any element.

id panel must contain the number of the panel. Example (1-tabs, tabs-2, ...)
Plugin subtracts 1 and open the panel. Tabs (active, (number of id -1))

Use

```
$("button.href").tabremote({panel:"#tabs",to:"data-href"});
```

panel:"#tabs" // container panel

to:"data-href" // attribute name with value

Answer (score 0):

```
function openTabByLink(link) {
    $("#tabs").find("ul li[aria-controls='"+link+"'] a").trigger("click");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use twitter bootstrap instead of jquery ui, it will be very simple. 
Just add `data-toggle="tab"` and put the link wherever you want in the page:

```
 <a href="#video" data-toggle="tab">Open Video Tab</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery UI 1.11

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">...</div>
...
<a href="#video" class="open-tab">Open Video Tab</a>
```

JS:

```
$('.open-tab').click(function () {
  $("#tabs").tabs('option','active',$('#tabs a.ui-tabs-anchor[href="'+$(this).attr('href')+'"]').index('#tabs a.ui-tabs-anchor'));
});
```