# MVC go to specific tab using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-tabs

I am doing this in .net MVC 4 &
I have made tabs using

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

I want to go in a specific tab for example in (Tab 4),
I am using this line of code but no Success,
here `(".btn")` is the class when the link is clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(".btn").click(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs('select', "#tab-4");
        });
</script>
```

I have also used some thing like this: `$("#tabs").tabs({"option", "", 3});`

Please tell me the raight way to get rid of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs, the option you are looking for is [active](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active):

`{ active: index }`

Where `index` is a zero-based index. So your code needs to be:

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs({ active: 3 });
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8L6dp/1/) of the above.

Comment: Dear I tried this also, but again same, it not worked,
and thanks to answer.

Comment: plz tell me where to write { active: index }

Comment: I am getting alert, but it does not go my specifeid tab.

Comment: Might be it working in Jquery, I am using this line of code in a VIew of my MVC application.

Comment: I used this and it did not work,
$("#tabs").tabs({ active: 3 });

Comment: Doing so I a getting this result,
alert($("#tabs").tabs({ active: 3 }));
[object Object]
plz tell any solution @RGraham